# Performance and alternatives for Java reflection for Play! framework Routes-like functionality

Tags: java, reflection, playframework, routes

I am creating a small Java web application, where I have defined a routes file, which specifies for each action the method of the controller that should be executed.

In order to do this, I parse this routes file, and in my main Servlet, based on the received call, I use reflection in order to invoke the required method.

However, Java reflection causes a performance overhead (based on the JVM, etc).

Thus I would like to ask, if this is the right procedure, or there is another alternative to perform such task.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to rewrite play framework. Why not use Play's routing instead?

Comment: You could also take a look at this router for SpringMVC https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router

Comment: What I would like is to understand how this routing works and which is the best way to implement such feature. Thanks also for the link, I 'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance overhead of invoking the method by reflection is negligible in this case: I estimate that a reflective method call will take on the order of 0.1 microseconds, while the network latency between client and server is easily 10 milliseconds. That is, less than 0.001% of response time is due to reflection overhead.

Take home message: When being told that something is "slow", always ask "compared to what", and try to assess whether it could conceivably have a measurable performance impact before optimizing it for performance. (And if you have an actual performance problem to solve, measure which parts of your program are slow, optimize those - and then measure again).

Answer (score 0):

Reflection seems to be the one way to do routing dynamically and with good feedback to the developer, all in a quick develop/test cycle.

As an alternative to remove the overhead one could imagine having a "compiling" step which would generate Java-code out of the routes file. But personally I would not recommend that.

In any case, stipulating that the performance is a problem seems to be premature without having measured it.